# Port forward with Ansible and firewalld

Tags: ansible

I  am experimenting with Ansible and want to set a port forward rule in firewalld.

I've tried the following:

```yaml
  - name: Port forward for 443
    become: true
    ansible.posix.firewalld:
      port_forward:
        - port: 443
          proto: tcp
          toport: 2443
      state: enabled
```

This resulted in:

```
ERROR: Exception caught: queryForwardPort() got an unexpected keyword argument ''to_port''
```

If I format it as a list it says

```
Only one port forward supported at a time
```

and if I format it as a dict I get:

```
argument port_forward is of type <class ''dict''> and we were unable to convert to list: <class ''dict''> cannot be converted to a list'
```

I'm using a Debian 11 VM with Ansible 2.10.8. I've installed the latest ansible.posix (1.3.0) as the included version was older (1.1.1). I can manually create the rule on the target machine (OEL 8).

This is as far as I got using the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/firewalld_module.html).

Any idea how to get this working?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like you're facing [a bug](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/issues/247) which as been fixed on the main branch but not yet released if I looked carrefully enough

Comment: @Zeitounator, right, according [`ansible.posix/plugins/modules/firewalld.py `](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/blob/main/plugins/modules/firewalld.py#L709) it seems to be simple enough that one can fix it on hisself within the collection files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a short glance there seems to be syntax errors. The first error message says

```
ERROR: Exception caught: queryForwardPort() got an unexpected keyword argument ''to_port''
```

`to_port`, whereby it should be `toport` according the linked documentation of the [`firewalld`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/firewalld_module.html#parameters)_module. Since your are on [`ansible.posix.collections`](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ansible/posix) v1.3.0 and there is bug report open according Ansible Collections Ansible Posix Issue #[247](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/issues/247), were downgrading to v1.2.0 fix the issue, another approach might be according Ansible Issue #[28349](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/28349) using the parameter `rich_rule`. That would work for v1.1.1 too.

```yaml
- name: Redirect port 443 to 8443
  firewalld:
    rich_rule: rule family={{ item }} forward-port port=443 protocol=tcp to-port=8443
    zone:      public
    permanent: true
    immediate: true
    state:     enabled
  with_items:
    - ipv4
    - ipv6
```

To get the older version you could use

```
ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix:1.2.0
```

The syntax error is in the file [`ansible.posix/plugins/modules/firewalld.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/blob/main/plugins/modules/firewalld.py#L709) and seems to be simple enough that one can fix it on hisself locally on behalf.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to edit the file based on this [PR](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/pull/248/files?file-filters%5B%5D=.py&show-viewed-files=true) - which as mentioned above already made it to the master branch just not released yet

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me as well. I rebuilt my awx-ee image with ansible.posix 1.2 and it is working as expected. I can also confirm that this is still an issue with 1.4, as that was my prior image's version of ansible.posix.